# $.ajax (jQuery v1.9.1) not work on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ipad

Ajax does not work only on the iPad

```
$.ajax({
    url         : 'http://www.othersite.com/GetUrl?Callback=?',
    dataType    : 'json',
    contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type        : 'GET',
    timeout     : 5000,
    cache       : false,
    crossDomain : true,
    async       : true,
    data        : { id : 100, noCache : new Date().getTime() },
    beforeSend  : function(XMLHttpRequest) { alert('Sended!'); },
    complete    : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) { alert('Completed with status: ' + textStatus) },
    success     : function(data){ alert('Success with response:' + data.response ); },
    error       : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){ alert('Error: ' + textStatus); }
});
```

Alerts on iPad

```
Sended!
Completed with status: timeout;
Error: timeout
```

Alerts in IE (7,8,9,10,11), Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari Desktop

```
Sended!
Completed with status: success
Success with response: http://www.google.com/
```

the server app (average response in 50ms)

```
echo $_GET['Callback'].'('.json_encode(array('response' => 'http://www.google.com/')).')';
```

Server Response Header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Length: 152
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 02 Dec 2014 09:52:46 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
```

Server Response Body

```
jQuery19109435868220625793_1417512417785({"response": "http://www.google.com/"})
```

In server logs there are requests from iPad, but appear all that from other browsers.

why is this happening?

Comment: It appears that the request from the iPad is timing out on the server. Without seeing what the server is doing on this request it's going to be next to impossible to answer this question.

Comment: simple `echo $_GET['Callback'].'('.json_encode(array('response' => 'http://www.google.com/')).')';`

Comment: Is your server certificate-protected?

Comment: @faby no certificate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari ignores the timeout settings in synchronous AJAX calls. If your page don't receive a response from server in 10 sec, it receives `NETWORK_ERR` error.

try adding a specific `timeout` property in your ajax call

```
timeout: 240000
```

**update**

It seems that it is not possible to change 10 seconds as he maximum timeout because Safari consider longer waits as "bad" for users. You can make async the call and use [promise](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)  to simulate the syncronous

Comment: The problem is not that the server is taking too long to respond. The server provides the average response in 50ms. In server logs there are requests from iPad, but appear all that from other browsers.

Comment: are you able to check if the calls arrives on your server?

Comment: Try passing `async:true` only on Ipad